# Using Loops to find the Difference between two Rows in the same Column

Tags: r, for-loop, operators

So I have a 252 rows of data in column 4, and I would like to find the difference between two consecutive rows throughout the entire column

My current code is:

```
appleClose<-NULL
for (i in 1:Apple[1]){
  appleClose[i] <- AA[i,4]
}
appleClose[]
```

I tried, and failed, with:

```
appleClose<-NULL
for (i in 1:Apple[1]){
  appleClose[i] <- AA[i,4] - AA[i+1,4]
}
appleClose[]
```

Edit:
I am trying to optimize a stock market portfolio in retrospect.
AA is the ticker symbol for Apple.  I downloaded that information through some **R** code written earlier in the program.
I have not yet checked out the diff function yet. I will do that now.

The error I am receiving is

> Error in `[.xts`(AA, i + 1, 4) : subscript out of bounds

Comment: What error do you get?  What is `Apple` and `AA`?  Without much data, it is hard to answer your question.  I would look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) about making a great reproducible example.

Comment: Have you checked out the `diff` function?

Comment: Yes, please produce a small reproducible example of input and expected output

Comment: He is probably getting out of bounds in his indexing.

Comment: use diff. or c(NA,x)-c(x,NA). why d'ya get an error? hard to tell from your cryptic notation but if you loop from 1 to length of x then x[i+1] won't exist

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you mean?

```
> Apple=runif(5,1,10)

#5 numbers
> Apple
[1] 3.362267 2.489085 3.899513 5.591127 9.315716

#4 differences
> diff(Apple)
[1] -0.8731816  1.4104271  1.6916143  3.7245894
```

or depending on your data either

```
>diff(AA$Apple)
```

or maybe

```
>diff(AA[,4])
```

Comment: the diff(AA[,4]) works, but skips over some days:
2013-08-30    -0.11
2013-09-03     0.02

Answer (score 0):

Another option (if you are referring to this, your question is not much clear)

> AA[-1,4]- AA[-dim(A)[1],4]